# Practical usage of Siegel-Walfisz Theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The Siegel-Walfisz theorem states that given a fixed N, there exists a $C_N >0$, only depending on $N$, such that  $\pi(x; q,a) =  \frac{Li(x)}{\phi(x)} + O(x\cdot e^{-\frac{C_N}{2}(\sqrt{\log{x}})})$ when $q \le \log^N{x} $

$C_N$ is not efficiently computable.

I am interested in explicitly bounding the error term and setting the interval it holds for. Something like $x > 23457$  and k = 1.1 (for example):

$\pi(x; q,a) \le  \frac{Li(x)}{\phi(x)} + k\cdot x\cdot e^{-\frac{C_N}{2}(\sqrt{\log{x}})}$

Is it possible? How could $k$ and $x_0$  be defined ? As you see, my problem comes from the $O()$ definition and handling properly it with a not known $C_N$

I know some effective definitions of Bombieri-Vinogradov theorem could be used, but I am very interested in relative small $q$ moduli.

Comment: Again **The reference** for this is [Iwaniec&Kowalski's](https://www.google.fr/search?q=iwaniec+kowalski+analytic+number+theory+pdf) book. $C_N$ is  computable : at worst enumerate the $\chi \bmod d \le q$ and compute the parameters involved in the prime number theorem and the Siegel zero. [Bombieri-Vinogradov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombieri%E2%80%93Vinogradov_theorem) is of not help for a fixed $a,q$. A google search gives immediatly [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.5322.pdf).

Comment: So, would you please mind helping me calculate $C_N$  for $q=3$ and $N=2$ I am happy with an upper bound of it.

Comment: I think this http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.363.540&rep=rep1&type=pdf is exactly providing $k, x_0, \epsilon$ to bound errors for small moduli.