# How to use Big O to establish an explicit bound

Tags: calculus

Imagine we have the next expression:

$f(n) = g(n) + O(e^{-c\cdot n})$

Where $c>0$ and $O()$ means Big O in the Landau notation.  An explicit upper bound of the form

$f(n) < g(n) + k\cdot e^{-c\cdot n}$

is required. Is there anyway to explicitly calculate a valid $k$ considering $g(n)$ has an explicit formula, but $f(n)$ has no explicit formula, although it is possible to numerically compute the first $n$ values for $f$.

I can easily compute a finite table of values $(n, f(n))$ up to $n_0$, and "pick" a $k$ big enough to assure  $\forall n\le n_0, f(n) < g(n) + k_0n^2$ but I have no guarantee that  $k_0$ may not be enough for a bigger $n > n_0$

Is there a formal way to provide an estimate of $k$ ? I understand that graphing both functions may provide a hint, but I do really need something formal.

Comment: Define $f_k(n) = g(n) + k\cdot e^{-cn}$. Which $k$ is the explicit bound?

Comment: That is exactly my question, how do I calculate an explicit value of $k$, such as $f_k(n) > f(n)$

Comment: As detailed in an answer this is impossible. And that's not just a quirk of the definition.  There are even actual problems in number theory for example where getting an explicit value in some O-formulas would be considered a major research achievement.

Comment: In theory this can be done by [unwinding](https://math.stanford.edu/~feferman/papers/unwind.pdf) but this requires so much proof theory and reverse mathematics that if you have to ask the answer is, for all practical purposes, “no”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not possible, as the constant $k$ (even if we know about its existence) can be arbitrarily large and the $N$ for which $f(n) < g(n) + k\cdot e^{-cn} \forall n>N$ holds can again be arbitrarily large.

If you say $f(n)-g(n) \in O(e^{-cn})$ you're saying by definition

$$\lim\sup_{n\to \infty} \frac{|f(n)-g(n)|}{e^{-cn}} < \infty$$

so that means that there is some $k$ and some $N$ such that $\frac{|f(n)-g(n)|}{e^{-cn}} < k$ forall $n > N$, but it says nothing about the size of $N$ or $k$.

Comment: By the way thanks for the answer. I believed this was the answer, but some other answers I got on a more specific question but essentially the same, has been misleading on this particular aspect.

Comment: Do you think the answer would change if the question would be: $f(n) \sim  g(n)$  Would it be possible to define a $K$ and $n_0$ for which we could grant $f_k(n>n_0) > g(n)$

Comment: No, the argument is again about the same as above. I recommend writing down the definition of $\tilde$ then it is easy to see.

Comment: The originating question was: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436506/practical-usage-of-siegel-walfisz-theorem  One more time thanks for precise and prompt answer as well as formatting advice!

Comment: Oh sorry, that was not meant as formatting advice - I expected $\sim$ to be `\tilde` :)